# html5 code using bootstrap framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="preview_timeline">
                        <div class="timeline_v1">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                        <div>
                                        <img src="images/notepad.png">
                                        <label>17 July</label></div>
                                </li>

                                <li>

                                    <div class="dox">
                                        <div class="dox_img">
                                            <img src="images/dox.png">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dox_write">
                                            <h3><span       class="dox_preview">preview</span>_timeline_v1.jpg<span class="tag"> TAG</span>   </h3>
                                            <p>Attached to the comment <u>timeline_wireframes</u> By <u>Bharat</u></p>
                                            <p><a href="#"><u>Download</u></a></p>
                                            <span class="timeline">timeline x</span>
                                        </div>  <!-- <!eodox write -->
                                    </div><!-- <! eo dox -->

                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Hi, I am doing this code using bootstrap framework, in which I have placed div within the li, but my first link element is coming near to the bottom of the div. I want them in a line.

Comment: Hi, Surbhi. Are you saying that you would like the "Download" link text to appear on the same line as the "Attached to the comment...By Bharat" text?

Comment: No, actually first li elements are coming bottom to the div, they are touching the bottom line of the div.  while the other list item is starting from top. so the both li elements are ending on the same ground but i want them to start from the same x-axis.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your `<li>`s to be beside each other bootstrap has  `list-inline`  class.

ex.

`<ul class="inline-list">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>`